# How to read an XML in java w/o DOM?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an XML file and reading the information using Xpath, I want to read the 'listings_Id' and 'budget_remaining' together.

XML example

```
<ads>
  <ad>
     <listing_ids>
      <listing_id>2235</listing_id>
      <listing_id>303</listing_id>
      <listing_id>394</listing_id>
     </listing_ids>
     <reference_id>11</reference_id>
     <net_ppe>0.55</net_ppe>
     <budget_remaining>50000.0</budget_remaining>
 </ad>
  <ad>
     <listing_ids>
       <listing_id>2896</listing_id>
     </listing_ids>
     <reference_id>8</reference_id>
     <net_ppe>1.5</net_ppe>
     <budget_remaining>1.3933399</budget_remaining>
  </ad>
 </ads>
```

I want to output it to a CSV file as the following

```
ListingId,BudgetRemaining
2235,50000
303,50000
394,50000
2896,1.39
```

Using the code

```
String expression = "/ads/ad/listing_ids/listing_id";
    System.out.println(expression);
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(docum, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    }

String expression1 = "/ads/ad/budget_remaining";
    System.out.println(expression1);
    NodeList nodeList1 = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression1).evaluate(docum, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList1.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodeList1.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    }
```

Output

```
  /ads/ad/listing_ids/listing_id
  2235
  303
  394
  2896
  /ads/ad/budget_remaining
  50000.0
  1.3933399
```

Desired Output

```
 2235,50000.0
 303,50000.0
 2896,50000.0
 2896,1.3933399
```

How to read the XML using Xpath or any other method? I want the 'listing_ids' and 'budget_ remaining' to be read together for each 'Listing Id' like

```
303,50000
```

Please help me-new to Java.

Comment: Check this out: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/

Comment: @MarkW : It was of no help to me . I have modified the question to the actual requirement, hope so it may help.

Comment: Does `expression` contain the actual expression you are sending?

Comment: You can use `//listing_ids/listing_id[2]` to obtain the `listing_id`. Do you expect to get the `net_ppe` associated with the ID? You can build an expression containing the ID you selected like this `"//ad[listing_ids/listing_id = " + id + "]/net_ppe"` and you will get the second value. I think with this and the tutorial above you might be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier for you to use jaxb to parse the XML into a list of ads.
You can then reference your Java list

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using XQuery, which unlike XPath can return structured results. (Or XPath 2.0, but if you're going to XPath 2.0 then you might as well go all the way to XQuery).

The relevant query is

```
string-join(
  for $n in /ads/ad/listing_ids/listing_id
  return $n/concat(., ',', ../../budget_remaining),
  '&#xa;'
)
```

This will return the required output as a single string.